# A very cherished person

Tags: word-choice

I am looking for a noun which has a meaning close to "someone whose presence is very cherished." Not charismatic, just liked by everybody. I found something like "godsend" but I am not only talking about being helpful.

Comment: The only noun I can think of is “Mensch,” a Yiddish loan word common in some parts of the US, but I think it does not have as broad a meaning as you want. It is easier to find suitable adjectives or phrases than nouns. “X is companionable, easy going, nice to have around, a good sort.”

Comment: Have you tried describing them as having "a heart of gold"?

Comment: AHD "gem"  b. A beloved or highly prized person.